# Open a link with multilpe profiles in chrome

Tags: visual-studio-code, puppeteer

I'm working with puppeteer on visual studio code and I want to create something to open multiple request of the same link but with different chrome profiles, ie: open "https://google.com" 40 times, with 40 different profiles (Profile "n") of Chrome
I use the next code to open one specific profile but i want to open 40 or more profiles

```
 executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
      args: ['--user-data-dir=\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\',
      '--profile-directory=Profile 3' ]
```

If there is anyways to do that with any type of coding will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Can you ensure you have enough ram and cpu to open 40 chrome windows at once? If yes, then let's work on a solution.

Comment: Yes, I do it manually but I want to automatize it